# How to read variable declarations involving volatile, const and *

Tags: c

I am having a bit of trouble with read this variable declaration. Could someone please give me a hand?

```
const int volatile * volatile const * const volatile * ptr;
```

Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: ptr is a const volatile pointer to a const volatile pointer to a const volatile int. And this wouldn't compile as all const declarations require an initializer.

Comment: @DeiDei, yes, it does: http://ideone.com/vZCKDn

Comment: IDEONE is not the best choice for a code checking.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive?

Answer (score 1):

Identifier ptr is a pointer to a const volatile pointer to a const volatile pointer to a const volatile int.

```
const int volatile * volatile const * const volatile * ptr;
```

Pointer: `* ptr`

to a const volatile pointer: `* const volatile`

to a const volatile pointer: `* volatile const`

to a const volatile int: `const int volatile`

As you can see the order of qualifiers around the type specifier doesn't matter. The definition is identical to:

```
const volatile int *const volatile *const volatile *ptr;
```